# Do I need to explicitly run an if statement before a while-loop?

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to the C# language and wondered something when writing code not so long ago. When I am writing while loops, I also find asking myself do I explicitly need to check if my while condition is even needed, lets take the following code for example.

```
while (_myList.Count > 0)
{
    // do some work
}
```

If previously written code (by other developers) I have seen them do something like this...

```
if (_list.Count > 0)
{
    while (_myList.Count > 0)
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Which is the best practice, do I even need to do this? If so why.. can someone shine some light on this topic and let me know whats best? Thanks.

Comment: second snippet is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the if:

```
if (_list.Count > 0)
```

**While loop**

> What a while loop does:  is taking an argument and compares whats left
>   from the operator to the the right. And returns a boolean (true or
>   false) as long the while gets a true it will continue the loop.

**IF**

> What an if statment does: is taking an argument and compares whats left
>   from the operator to the the right. And returns a boolean (true or
>   false) as long the if gets a true it will continue and run the code in the if code block.

**notice:**

```
if (_list.Count > 0) // checking for _list
{
   while (_myList.Count > 0) // checking for _myList
   { 
   }
}
```

In the example you have shown the "Other developer" you check on different situations so in this case it can be usefull to check on _list.Count if you don't want to run te loop when _list.Count > 0.

**Conclusion**

*Don't do:* it when you checkking on teh same list in the if and wile.

*Can do:* if you only want to run the wile on an certain condition or possible exception.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to add an `if` in this case.

Before entering `while` condition will be evaluated and you don't iterate if <= 0.

Caution in your sample you speak of `_list` and `my_list` which isn't the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The second code example is useless. If list count is 0 or smaller, the while wouldn't be executed.

However, you have to check, if `_myList` is null, maybe like this:

```
if (_myList == null)
    //error handling here
```

if `_myList` really was null, then you'd have a `NullReferenceException` in both your code examples.